# Python Multithread/process to fill in matrix with values

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, python-3.6, python-multiprocessing

I have this code below, I already optimised the algorithm to make it as fast as possible but it is still too slow. So a was thinking about using multiprocessing (I have no expierience with this kind of stuff), but I tried some things with pool and threading but either it was slower than before or didn't work. So is was wondering how I should do this so that it works and is faster. And if there are other options than multithreading to make kind of code this faster.

```
def calc(indices, data):
    matrix = [[0] * len(indices) for i in range(len(indices))]
    for i_a, i_b in list(itertools.combinations(indices, 2)):
        a_res, b_res = algorithm(data[i_a], data[i_b])
       matrix[i_b][i_a] = a_res
       matrix[i_a][i_b] = b_res
    return matrix


def algorithm(a,b):
   # Verry slow and complex
```

Comment: Have you checked out the [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/) library? It may help.

Comment: I'm already using Numpy in the actual algorithm, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon **Simon**'s answer, here is an example applying a `multiprocessing` pool to a version of your problem. Your mileage will vary depending on how many cores you have on your machine but I hope that this will be a helpful demonstration of how you could structure a solution to your problem:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def calc_mp(indices, data):
    # construct pool
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    # we are going to populate the matrix; organize all the inputs; then map them
    matrix = [[0] * len(indices) for i in range(len(indices))]
    args = [(data[i_a], data[i_b]) for i_a, i_b in list(itertools.combinations(indices, 2))]
    results = pool.starmap(algorithm, args)

    # unpack the results into the matrix
    for i_tuple, result in zip([(i_a, i_b) for i_a, i_b in list(itertools.combinations(indices, 2))], results):
        # unpack
        i_a, i_b = i_tuple
        a_res, b_res = result

        # set it in the matrix
        matrix[i_b][i_a] = a_res
        matrix[i_a][i_b] = b_res

    return matrix

def calc_single(indices, data):
    # do the simple single process version
    matrix = [[0] * len(indices) for i in range(len(indices))]
    for i_a, i_b in list(itertools.combinations(indices, 2)):
        a_res, b_res = algorithm(data[i_a], data[i_b])
        matrix[i_b][i_a] = a_res
        matrix[i_a][i_b] = b_res

    return matrix

def algorithm(a,b):
    # Very slow and complex
    time.sleep(2)
    return a + b, a - b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # generate test data;
    indices = range(5)
    data = range(len(indices))

    # test single
    time_start = time.time()
    print(calc_single(indices, data))
    print("Took {}".format(time.time() - time_start))

    # mp
    time_start = time.time()
    print(calc_mp(indices, data))
    print("Took {}".format(time.time() - time_start))
```

The results, with 8 cores, are

```
[[0, -1, -2, -3, -4], [1, 0, -1, -2, -3], [2, 3, 0, -1, -2], [3, 4, 5, 0, -1], [4, 5, 6, 7, 0]]
Took 20.02155065536499
[[0, -1, -2, -3, -4], [1, 0, -1, -2, -3], [2, 3, 0, -1, -2], [3, 4, 5, 0, -1], [4, 5, 6, 7, 0]]
Took 4.073369264602661
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really  helped me out. Because I was looking in to how to make multiprocessing  work, but I just didn't think about just filling in the results in the matrix after the whole  .starmap() had been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet in [Multiprocessing](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html). You will need to partition your data into chunks and pass each chunk to a process. Threading won't help you in Python because all Python processes run on a single cpu thread. [It's still useful for some use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python/3045648#3045648), such as where you have several activities going on some of which might block, but not for parallel workloads.